# What are the common tennis terms in Chinese?

Tags: translation, vocabulary

Particularly for

- [advantage set / tiebreaker set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_scoring_system#Scoring_a_tiebreak_game)
- game
- set
- match
- love (the term used for 0 or a no score situation)
- 15/30/40
- deuce
- advantage in / advantage out

Answer (score 1):

advantage set 长盘

tiebreaker set 抢七

game 局

set 盘

match 场

love (the term used for 0 or a no score situation) ：0

15/30/40 ： 15/30/40 （the same）

deuce : 平分

advantage in： 发球占先

advantage out : 接发占先

（btw. advantage is 占先）

Comment: @songyuanyao Sorry, will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

tennis term：网球术语

advantage set / tiebreaker set 长盘赛制

game 局

set 盘

match 场

love (the term used for 0 or a no score situation):零分

15/30/40：十五/三十/四十
（一种计分方式）

deuce：平分

advantage in / advantage out：can‘t found 平分后本方得一分，平分后对方得一分

solution:
when you got stuck on the tennis term,just use [google](http://www.google.com) or [baidu](http://www.baidu.com)
1、search like this 
XX 网球  or  XX 网球术语

2、where you can found like:

[网球术语](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B6%B2%E7%90%83%E8%A1%93%E8%AA%9E%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8)

[百度网球术语](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/6559d6f59e31433239689329.html)